# Gnuplot: Plotting residuals

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a visualization of the least square method. In the end it should look like this: 
[image: Resudual]

Right now I have the data points and I have the fitted curve (a straight line in my case, called f(x)). What I am missing are the residuals (in the link the residuals are the green lines).
Meaning: I want to draw lines starting at each data point going vertically to the fitted line.

My data.txt looks like this (shortend)

```
1, 3
2, 4
3, 6
4, 3
```

My gnuplot commands are:

```
f(x) = a*x +b  + 1e-9
fit f(x) 'data.txt' u 1:2  via a, b
plot 'data.txt' with points title 'data',  f(x)
```

So far with I only managed to have the residuals as impulses using

```
plot 'data.txt' with points title 'data',  '' using 1:($2 - f($1)) w impulse, f(x)
```

but like that, the start from y=0 und go up down, they are not between the fitted line f(x) and the data point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `errorbars` here:

```
 plot 'data.txt' with points title 'data',\
      f(x) notitle,\
      'data.txt' u ($1):(f($1)):(f($1)):2 w yerrorbars title 'residuals'
```

There's also the `errorlines` style which you could use basically the same:

```
 plot 'data.txt' with points title 'data',\
      'data.txt' u ($1):(f($1)):(f($1)):2 w yerrorlines title 'residuals'
```

but in this case, the line (`f(x)`) is plotted with the same style that the residuals are plotted.

Comment: The first part is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! A side note for others with similar problems: I had to change the style of the points using ...`with points 4`... to make the points better distinguishable from the residuals.

Comment: @albifant -- I thought the first one was what you wanted, but I included the second as it seemed close and might help someone else.  You might want to be more explicit about what you're changing with the points.  You can change the pointsize (`ps`) or the pointtype (`pt`):  ... `with points ps 2 pt 4`

Comment: I was under the impression that when you leave out `pt` and just go for `with points 4` it would behave like an implicit `with points pt 4`, but it is not exactly the same. The resulting point style is in fact the same, but the color it is not. So both versions work, `with points pt 4` is imho more elegant.